# Rails dropping last value in array when saving to Postgres database as JSON array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I am building a web app using Rails and Postgres. I am trying to save an array into my database table and it is only deleting the last value in the array.

For example if my array is:

```
a= [10,12,14,16]
```

I would do `@table.column = a.json`

When I do `byebug a.json = [10,12,14,16]` however if I get the value of `@table.column` it is equal to `[10,12,14]`. This happens for all arrays I save to my database.

The column schema is:

```
t.text "name", default: [], array: true
```

[Screenshot of byebug for my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1df47.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) instance public method, so in your model do :

```
serialize :steves_journey_passed, Array
```

Then, retry to save your array without .to_json method.

I hope it helped you !